# 18.04 errors preventing normal boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

My ubuntu is only booting in recovery mode after I pressed the power button on my laptop while it was connected to a Samsung TV, and before resuming I disconnected from the TV, that made it get totally lost.

Here is my log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UuPk2RadQ5HS1h1LoE7eH5nbk4pL8o-j/view?usp=sharing

Here is a picture of the screen when trying to boot:

[image]

Please let me know if I should provide more info

- System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit
- Memory: 12GB
- CPU: Intel I7 6500u
- DE: Gnome 3.28.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself by running ubuntu in recovery mode and selecting the option to recover the packages, after it ran and rebooted the system was back to normal 100%...
Not sure what happened though, would love for someone to take a look at the logs and let me know what is it that I did wrong to break the normal boot